# Как написать регулярное выражение для такой строки?

Tags: python, re

Всем привет и хорошого дня. Хочу написать регулярное выражение для адреса места жительства. Мне нужен шаблон, который можно использовать и по адресу с номером квартиры и без.

> tex = 'Иванов В.В.  адрес Володимирська 7 ТЕЛЕФОН 0963412678   1000
> адр. Схудна 8 телефон 0667835467  Гоц Маша 560
> Кот Женя      АДРЕС Леваневського 3 кв 6      тел. 0673426450 270
> АДР. Гризодубово 45 кв 102   Бондар Ю.С.  ТЕЛ. 0971524366 15000000'

Я пыталась сделать это таким способом

```
import re
adress2 = r'((адр.|АДР.|адрес|АДРЕС)\s[А-Яа-я]+\s\d+\sкв\s\d+)'
res2 = re.findall(adress2, tex)
print(res2)
```

вывод такой

```
[('АДРЕС Леваневського 3 кв 6', 'АДРЕС'), ('АДР. Гризодубово 45 кв 102', 'АДР.')]
```

возможно ли сделать вывод таким?

```
[('адрес Володимирська 7', 'адрес'), ('адр.Схудна 8', 'адр.'),('АДРЕС Леваневського 3 кв 6', 'АДРЕС'), ('АДР. Гризодубово 45 кв 102', 'АДР.')]
```

Comment: а если название улицы не из одного слова? а если в названии улицы есть цифры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще не уверен, что подобный поиск по зубам регуляркам, но можно попробовать как-то так:

```
res = [x[0] for x in re.findall(r"адр.+?\s(.*?\d+(\sкв \d+)?)\s", tex, flags=re.IGNORECASE)]
```

res:

```
['Володимирська 7',
 'Схудна 8',
 'Леваневського 3 кв 6',
 'Гризодубово 45 кв 102']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, все работает!